# Way to iterate through entire mongo database that is too large to load?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I must do some data processing for one of my company's clients. They have a database of about 4.7GB of data. I need to add a field to each of these documents calculated using two properties of the mongo documents and an external reference.

My problem is, I can not do collection.find() because Node.js runs out of memory. What is the best way to iterate through an entire collection that is too large to load with a single call to find?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507866/how-can-i-use-a-cursor-foreach-in-mongodb-using-node-js

Comment: Fantastic, I'm flagging this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, there is a way. Mongo is designed to handle large datasets.

You are probably running out of memory, not because of `db.collection.find()`, but because you are trying to dump it all at once with something like `db.collection.find().toArray()`.

The correct way to operate over resultsets that are bigger than memory is to use cursors. Here's how you'd do it in mongo console:

```
var outsidevars = {
   "z": 5
};

var manipulator = function(document,outsidevars) {
    var newfield = document.x + document.y + outsidevars.z;
    document.newField = newfield;
    return document;
};

var cursor = db.collection.find();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    // load only one document from the resultset into memory
    var thisdoc = cursor.next();
    var newnoc = manipulator(thisdoc,outsidevars);
    d.collection.update({"_id": thisdoc['_id']},newdoc);
};
```

Comment: Good answer, however I asked how to do it in node.js, not in the mongo console. The linked question in the comments has a better answer, so I'm flagging this as a duplicate.

Comment: How does it compare with cursor's forEach method?

Comment: Currently, the method to get the document is `next()`, not `getNext()`.

Comment: Thanks @StevenSpungin. I changed it

Comment: How does this work on a live database that has writes coming in at the same time as running this script. Will the new documents be included in the iteration? Also am I right that this will lock up the database and I should add a timeout between every update?