# Node Js forEach unable to get result

Tags: node.js, foreach

Im trying to get iterate the results array variable.

I am able to get the array values inside the function, but when i try to log it outside it shows null.

Wen i googled few posts, i see that forEach was not recommended, suggested was for loop, i tried even that and i get null for result.

What is the issue in cursor.forEach()...

```
 router.get('/getlist', function(req, res, handleError) {
    client.connect('mongodb://localhost', function(err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var db = client.db('angular-demo');
        var collection = db.collection("api_details");
        var query = {};
        var cursor = collection.find(query);
        var results = new Array();
        var results = cursor.forEach(
            function(result) {
                return result;

                console.log("insert")
                console.log(results);
            }
        );

        console.log("append")
        console.log(results); //results here shows null
    });
 });
```

**Log result:**

```
append
[]

insert
[ { _id: 5a6867c8e54f6120709eabc5,
app_id: 'CaseRegistration',
description: 'API to register cases in the system',
cost_per_usage: '0.5',
__v: 0 } ]

insert
[ { _id: 5a6867c8e54f6120709eabc5,
app_id: 'CaseRegistration',
description: 'API to register cases in the system',
cost_per_usage: '0.5',
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 5a6867fde54f6120709eabc6,
app_id: 'CheckCreation',
description: 'CREs create the case with minimal data and assigns it to case initiation team to create checks',
cost_per_usage: '1',
__v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Your solution lies in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507866/how-can-i-use-a-cursor-foreach-in-mongodb-using-node-js

Comment: You can more read about foreach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab results from `find` you can use [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray)

```
cursor.toArray(function (error, documents) {
    console.log(documents)
})
// or
cursor.toArray().then(function (documents) {
    console.log(documents)
})
// or in async function
const documnets = await cursor.toArray()
```

or if you need to transform them somehow use [`map`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#map)

Answer (score 0):

It's not relevant if you use `forEach` or `for` loop in this case. The `results` variable isn't being populated because you're trying to populate it with the return result from the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which doesn't return anything useful.

What you want to do, is just iterate over the results, and fill the `results` array while iterating.

Something more like this :

```
var results = [];
cursor.forEach(
    function(result) {
         results.push(result);
    }
);

console.log(results); // This should be populated now
```