# MongoDB issue in query returning value from user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am using MongoDB with Nodejs and I am trying to find the usertype value of a specific user so I've got this:

```
var myQuery= { username: req.body.username }, { "usertype": 1 };
 dbo.collection("usercollection").find(myQuery, function(err, obj) { ...
```

What I need returned is the value of usertype from that specific user but it keeps saying I have a syntax error with : expected.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommends to first perform the find operation to get the cursor and after it extract data from the cursor like below,

```
var myQuery= { username: req.body.username };
dbo.collection("usercollection").find(myQuery, {  projection: { usertype: 1}  }).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
```

In your case, the above code will work fine.

Comment: also, find's 2nd param requires a separate object of projection, please check in the above code!

Comment: It's returning 1 on usertype ... it's a string ... I don't expect usertype to be 1 ... I just need to get the value of whatever usertype value is ... I might have not explain myself properly.

Comment: remove projection and check whether it is returning the complete user object!

Comment: I've tried console.log(obj); and it's returning way too much info back.

Comment: and it is also containing the user type?

Comment: also, as of the above code, you should console.log(result) instead of body!

Comment: No, just a lot of other information: eg: raw: undefined,
[1]      hint: null,
[1]      timeout: undefined,
[1]      slaveOk: false,
[1]      readPreference: null },
[1]   options:
[1]    { skip: 0,
[1]      limit: 0,
[1]      raw: undefined,
[1]      hint: null,
[1]      timeout: undefined,
[1]      slaveOk: false,
[1]      readPreference: null,
[1]      db:
[1]       Db {
[1]         _events: {},
[1]         _eventsCount: 0,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         s: [Object],
[1]         serverConfig: [Getter],
[1]         bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],

Comment: this is the cursor data, did you use the above code `toArray`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error since you're trying to define query and [projection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find) for [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method in one line, try:

```
var myQuery= { username: req.body.username };
var options = { projection: { usertype: 1 } };
var cursor = dbo.collection("usercollection").find(myQuery, options)
```

Comment: It's returning 1 on usertype ... it's a string ... I don't expect usertype to be 1 ... I just need to get the value of whatever usertype value is ... I might have not explain myself properly.

Comment: If you use node.js driver for Mongo then you need to add `projection` as a top level property, check my modified answer

Comment: Tried it but same issue console.log(obj); returns a lot of crap and no db fields info

Comment: @monroe2019 I think the reason is that you're dealing with cursors in node.js driver. You can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507866/how-can-i-use-a-cursor-foreach-in-mongodb-using-node-js to check how to work with them