# Easiest way to load documents from MongoDB collection in chunks of 10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create an application that creates orders and then loads them on a list. The problem is that I cannot load all orders at once. I want to load them 10 by 10.

However, this looks very difficult to do in MongoDB, as there are no automatic id like in SQL. I know how to simulate an automatic id, but I think it should be easier to implement this feature.

So, given a MongoDB collection, how do I load documents 10 by 10, starting from the latest one up to the beggining?

Comment: You could probably use a [`Cursor`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursor.html) with a limit and a sort. You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507866/how-can-i-use-a-cursor-foreach-in-mongodb-using-node-js).

Comment: @cubrr I think I forgot to specify that I access things from a REST API, so I cannot use a cursor because it requires state to be saved

Comment: Open a cursor with a batchSize of 10 with whatever sort option you need, each time you process 10 documents, the driver should automatically fetch the next batch of 10

Comment: @Joe but this way the API is not REST because I must maintain a state. That is, the cursor needs to be kept on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort your document by a field then use [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) & [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) aggregation. Also to get the total number of records we can use [facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation.

Here is a detailed explanation:

Let's say you have these 8 documents in orders collection.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e390fc33285e463a0799689",
        "customer": "Max",
        "total": 10,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:31.311Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e390fd03285e463a079968a",
        "customer": "John",
        "total": 9.2,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:44.190Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e390fda3285e463a079968b",
        "customer": "Smith",
        "total": 11.3,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:54.248Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e390fdf3285e463a079968c",
        "customer": "Smith",
        "total": 12.3,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:59.993Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e390fec3285e463a079968d",
        "customer": "Jimmy",
        "total": 15.6,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:32:12.336Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e390ffd3285e463a079968e",
        "customer": "Wesley",
        "total": 11,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:32:29.670Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e3910163285e463a079968f",
        "customer": "Adam",
        "total": 6.1,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:32:54.131Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e3910213285e463a0799690",
        "customer": "Michael",
        "total": 7.2,
        "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:33:05.166Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

If we wanted to get these documents in chunks, we can write a sample route like this:

```js
router.get("/orders", async (req, res) => {
  const page = req.query.pageIndex ? +req.query.pageIndex : 1;
  const limit = req.query.pageSize ? +req.query.pageSize : 10;
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  const result = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $sort: {
        orderDate: -1
      }
    },
    {
      $facet: {
        totalRecords: [{ $count: "total" }],
        data: [{ $skip: skip }, { $limit: limit }]
      }
    }
  ]);
  res.send(result);
});
```

We send the pageIndex and pageSize parameters in query string like this `http://...../orders?pageIndex=1&pageSize=3`

When we use `pageIndex=1` and `pageSize=3`, the result will be like this: (as you see we also return the total number of records so that client can build the pagination numbers)

```
[
    {
        "totalRecords": [
            {
                "total": 8
            }
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "5e3910213285e463a0799690",
                "customer": "Michael",
                "total": 7.2,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:33:05.166Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e3910163285e463a079968f",
                "customer": "Adam",
                "total": 6.1,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:32:54.131Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e390ffd3285e463a079968e",
                "customer": "Wesley",
                "total": 11,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:32:29.670Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When we use `pageIndex=2` and `pageSize=3`, the result will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "totalRecords": [
            {
                "total": 8
            }
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "5e390fec3285e463a079968d",
                "customer": "Jimmy",
                "total": 15.6,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:32:12.336Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e390fdf3285e463a079968c",
                "customer": "Smith",
                "total": 12.3,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:59.993Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e390fda3285e463a079968b",
                "customer": "Smith",
                "total": 11.3,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:54.248Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When we use `pageIndex=3` and `pageSize=3`, the result will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "totalRecords": [
            {
                "total": 8
            }
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "5e390fd03285e463a079968a",
                "customer": "John",
                "total": 9.2,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:44.190Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e390fc33285e463a0799689",
                "customer": "Max",
                "total": 10,
                "orderDate": "2020-02-04T06:31:31.311Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For your case, you need to send 10 as pageSize value.

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna give you a bounty for this tomorrow.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I am happy that you liked my answer, accepting this as answer will be enough for me, you are very kind.

Comment: Just a question: in an aggregation pipeline, do thins occur atomically? In the first step of the data pipeline, it skips x and limits y. It it possible that, while it is skiping those x, a new document is added?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs good question, honestly I don't know, but If I find the answer I will comment here. But in general this will work well.

Comment: Since we can count the total number of documents, can aggregation be used to create a new document with auto increment id? Please take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60064892/can-mongodb-aggregation-be-used-to-create-auto-increment-id

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs we use aggregation framework for querying, it is not used for creating a new document.

Comment: I just noticed a major problem with your approach: if a new document is added while I'm scrolling to a list that load them 10 by 10, I will get repeated documents, as the newly inserted document will shift the number of documents I skip :(

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I didn’t understand exactly how repetition happens, can you give a scenario on the documents in my answer?

Comment: Since you made ithe `orderDate` descending, `pageIndex=1 and pageSize=2` will give `Michel` and `Adam`. Then someone adds an order for `Lucas`. If you do `pageIndex=2 and pageSize=2` now you'll get `Adam` and `Lucas`. See that `Adam` repeated. So if someone adds while you're scrolling, it gives repeated items

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs this scenario is not specific to this solution, it may happen in every paging solution, and actually it is not repetition since we don’t show the same record duplicated in one page. I think this is the best paging solution you can find for mongodb.